# How to just reopen all files in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I have about 400 files open in my Emacs session. I was configuring some modes and all my buffers changed to `fundamental-mode`.

Now, when I open a file Emacs chooses the correct major mode, but the already opened files are still in fundamental mode. How do I force Emacs to reopen all the opened files and choose the right mode for each of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
(defun aak/auto-mode-anywhere ()
  (interactive)
  (dolist (buffer (buffer-list))
    (with-current-buffer buffer
      (when (and
             (eq major-mode 'fundamental-mode)
             (buffer-file-name))
         (set-auto-mode)))))
```

`M-x aak/auto-mode-anywhere` won't exactly "reopen" files (no reverting or reloading), but it will set appropriate major mode for `fundamental-mode` buffers that are visiting files (based on `auto-mode-alist` etc.).

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ibuffer` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>*</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> `fundamental-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd> -- to mark all fundamental-mode buffers
- <kbd>E</kbd> `(normal-mode)` <kbd>RET</kbd> -- evaluate elisp in selected buffers
- <kbd>*</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd> -- remove all marks
- <kbd>q</kbd> -- dismiss the ibuffer buffer